# Plotting Fourier series for determined function

Tags: matlab, plot, fft

```
a=[0,pi/2,pi/2,pi];
b=[0,-1,0,0];
plot(a,b)
hold on
n=50;
ao=-pi/4;
T=[0,pi,0,1];
for i=1:length(T)
    t=linspace(a(i),b(i));
end
suma=0;
for i=1:n 
    bn=cos(pi*i)/2/i;
    an=(1-cos(pi*i))/4/(i)^2;
    suma=suma+(bn.*sin(2.*i.*t))+(an.*cos(2.*i.*t));
end
series=ao/2+suma;
plot(t,series)
```

[image: figure]

I need to plot two functions: determined function and its Fourier series, but I have some problem in plotting Fourier, it's not combined with the first one. I can guess that the problem in `t` or in `T`, but have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: You assume your problem is with the plotting, but I'd say it is likely on the definition of `a0`,`an` or `bn`. Can you show us how you derived those?

Comment: it looks like inside the for loops you keep updating the same variables, rather than defining the new ones on every step

Comment: @MikhailGenkin that should not be a problem, OP is using them within the loop too. As long as `an` and `bn` are properly derived.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, you are right. But look at the first loop, `t=linspace(a(i),b(i));`

Comment: @MikhailGenkin you are absolutely right.

Comment: @AnderBiguri  I estimated a0 , an and bn  by myself ,using formulas  (my aasignment isnt to do it code)

Comment: @ZlataBraginski *Can you show us how you derived those?*

Comment: https://pp.userapi.com/c850636/v850636407/3d9e0/uhi0DbQlPnU.jpg

Comment: I found some mistakes , but there has to be more of them))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your coefficients are incorrect. You should get:

```
a0 = -.5;
an = -(1/pi)*sin(pi*i)/i + (2/(pi^2*i^2))*sin((pi*i)/2)^2;
bn = -(1/(pi^2*i^2))*sin(pi*i) + 1/(pi*i)*cos(pi*i);
```

Then, as others pointed out, you want to use a single, long time vector:

```
t = linspace(a(1),a(end),1e3);
```

Using this code produces the graph you desire

```
a = [0,pi/2,pi/2,pi];
b = [0,-1,0,0];
plot(a,b)
hold on
n = 50;
T = [0,pi,0,1];

a0 = -.5;
t = linspace(a(1),a(end),1e3);
suma=0;
for i=1:n
    bn = -(1/(pi^2*i^2))*sin(pi*i) + 1/(pi*i)*cos(pi*i);
    an = -(1/pi)*sin(pi*i)/i + (2/(pi^2*i^2))*sin((pi*i)/2)^2;
    suma = suma+(bn.*sin(2.*i.*t))+(an.*cos(2.*i.*t));
end
series = a0/2 + suma;
plot(t,series)
```

[image: Plot from code above]

It should be noted that since this function is not smooth (there is a jump discontinuity) you will experience the Gibbs phenomenon and will see spikes near the discontinuity.